# DT_DBDATE date to YYYYMMDD in dervived column transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

I want to convert my column of transdate into YYYYMMDD format. In sql server I use this query

```sql
SELECT FORMAT([transdate],'yyyyMMdd')
```

It is running perfectly but I want to do this step using the derived column in SSIS please help. The data type is `DT_DBDATE.`

I used the following query but it is not working.

```cs
(DT_DBDATE)((YEAR(transdate) * 10000) + (MONTH(transdate) * 100) + DAY(transdate))

The reason of converting date into string format is basically i created a date table and i extracted this date from trans_date. Now i have to make dateid from that date That's why I converted it into int for further work especially for denormalization step.
```

Comment: I don't know about SSIS, but the datatype `DT_DBDATE` sounds like a true datetime type, so that would mean there is no format.

Comment: Why are you using string in the first place? The problem is you're using a `varchar(8)` instead of a strongly typed data type. Use a date and time data type in the first place, and there's no need for that expression.

Comment: In sql, this column data type is date and i have to convert date into yyyymmdd format. And in sql i easily convert this using format function but i am beginner i don't know how to convert it in ssis

Comment: Your result is int, not date... the mentioned format yyyymmdd is what you might get from `CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), DateCol, 112) AS INT)` in a query. So your calculation looks fine, but the DT_DBDATE should be replaced e.g. by DT_I4

Comment: @zararana *why* do you want to convert the date to a string at all? Humans rarely expect the unseparated format. When exporting to text files, ISO8601 is a far better idea. When talking to databases the best option is to use the date value, not convert it to a string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use data conversion task to convert you date column with datatype `DT_DBDATE` to `DT_WSTR`, then use the converted column in the expresion to get the result

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING([ConvertedDate], 1, 4) + SUBSTRING([ConvertedDate], 6, 2)  + SUBSTRING([ConvertedDate], 9, 2))
```

Comment: [Derived Column [44]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform data conversion. The source type could not be converted to the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

When converting `DT_DBDATE` to a string, the date value is formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`. You can simply remove the dashes `-` using a replace function as following:

```
REPLACE((DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBDATE)[ConvertedDate],"-","")
```

For more information you can refer to the official SSIS documentation:

- [Cast (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag the derived column and use this expression:
   (YEAR(input_datetime_col) * 10000) + (MONTH(input_datetime_col) * 100) + DAY(input_datetime_col) and add as a new column.
2. Drag the data conversion, and convert it into four-byte signed integer [DT_I4]
3. Map this new column to your destination.

Comment: That's not what you asked. The requiirement to store the date as a *number* is even weirder than storing it as a string and strongly suggests of either a misunderstanding about dates, or a hacky design. Dates have no storage and conversion issues. Dates as strings, or dates as integers have a *ton* of issues. What is the *actual problem* you want to solve?

Comment: I only want to convert my date into yyyymmdd format in short i don't need slashes in my dates. So, this is done by my above answer.

Comment: Again, dates are binary values, they have no format or slashes. Using the wrong type to store dates, whether it's a string, double or integer is a bug. You have *no* way of preventing bad data if you use the wrong type, no way to use meaningful indexing or use date functions. Why are you introducing this bug? What problem is this trying to solve? It's not format - there's none. It's not space - `date` is 3 bytes. It's not compatibility or localization - they don't apply since there's no format

Comment: And yes i solved it in sql server but in ssis i am beginner so its new for me to convert this using derived column